# Ionic2 checkbox with formControlName

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Actually I am stuck with an issue when using checkbox in ionic2.

I am using checkbox as:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Agree</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="dark" id="agree" name='agree' class="form-control" formControlName="agree" [checked]="false" ></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

In .ts i am fetching its value as :

```
console.log(this.timelogForm.controls['agree'].value);
```

I want it to be unchecked initially.

My issues are :

1. on using formControlName="agree" it is checked ..
2. I get its value in .ts if it is once clicked but I want if it's not clicked on submit I get false and if checked I get true..

Any help please

Comment: check the same by removing attribute `[checked]="false"` from `ion-checkbox`

Comment: I removed it but same two issues : It is checked by default and i have to click it once to get it value but i want it to be unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it on my own hope it helps someone..

I set its value as false like:

```
this.logForm = formBuilder.group({
        'agree': ['false'],
    });
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

## test.ts

```
buildForm(){
    this.accountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        generalTerms: ['', Validators.requiredTrue]
    });
}
```

## test.html

```
<form [formGroup]="accountForm">
    <ion-item class="center">
        <ion-checkbox formControlName="generalTerms" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
        <ion-label>Accepter les conditions générale</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="button" lines="none">
        <ion-button color="primary [disabled]="accountForm.invalid" 
        (click)="save()">
        Valider
        </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

Comment: Some words explaining your code would make your answer more useful

Comment: Set the default value to false within``generalTerms: ['false', Validators.requiredTrue]`` instead of setting ``checked`` attribute on ``ion-checkbox`` to ``false``

Answer (score 0):

Its working. I hope it will help you.

**test.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
export class test implements OnInit {
    logform: FormGroup;
    forgotPasswordEmail: any;
    constructor(private _navCtrl: NavController, private _fb: FormBuilder) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.logform = this._fb.group({
            ckeckbox: ['false', Validators.required]
        });
    }
}
```

**test.html**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Daenerys Targaryen</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="dark" formControlName="ckeckbox" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ionic standalone components, and in my case, i forgot to import **IonCheckbox** in the module

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm" class="auth-form">
.
.
    <ion-item lines="none" mode="ios">
        <ion-checkbox name="checkbox" mode="md" slot="start" formControlName="termCondition"></ion-checkbox>
        <ion-label>Accept</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
.
.
</form>
```

TS

```
signUpForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    termCondition: new FormControl<boolean>(false),
});
```

module.ts

import "IonCheckbox" in ngModule, from @ionic/angular/standalone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).